# ¿Puedo cerrar varios Form de una sola vez y dejar uno abierto en C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un login y un menú, y a su vez el menú tiene varios formularios.

Lo que deseo hacer es que al dar click sobre *cerrar sesión* en el menú, éste cierre (si es que hay) los demás formularios y me abra el login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el evento click del menú:

```
foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms){
    if (frm != this)    //Cerramos todos los formularios menos el formulario principal que contiene el menú
        frm.Close();
}
LoginForm login = new LoginForm();
login.ShowModal();
```

Answer (score 2):

Cuando clickes sobre Cerrar Sesión tienes que iterar por los formularios abiertos de la aplicación y cerrarlos, acto seguido abres el nuevo form de login.

```
FormCollection formulariosApp = Application.OpenForms;
foreach (Form f in formulariosApp ){
    //tus acciones
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El menú desde donde se cierra la sesión debería tener un evento. Deberías suscribirte a dicho evento desde la clase que controla el ciclo de vida de todas las ventanas y de esa forma podrías cerrar las ventanas llamando al método Close sobre cada formulario. Luego deberías instanciar el formulario de login y mostrarlo en pantalla. Sube el código relevante para que podamos ayudarte de forma más concreta.

Answer (score 0):

Tal cual como dijo lyrqs (https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/27492/17754)

```
FormCollection formulariosApp = Application.OpenForms;
foreach (Form f in formulariosApp ){
   if (f.Name != "frmLogin") {
       f.close();
   }
}
```

No estoy seguro si es:

```
f.close();
```

ó

```
f.hide();
```

Espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Quiza sea algo vieja esta pregunta, pero a alguien le servirá, yo tenia el mismo problema, trate de iterarlo con el foreach y es como que el «Application.Operform.close» no funcionara», en mi caso tenia un login, una ventana principal y un agregar producto, en total tenia 4 ventanas abiertas (porque el login solo lo oculte), y queria que cuando presionara el boton de Logout se cerrarán todas las ventanas (las 4)

```
    \\Declaramos una lista de tipo Form
    List<Form> formularios = new List<Form>();

    
    \\Recorremos Application.OpenForms el cual tiene la lista de formularios y metemos todos los forms en la lista que declaramos
    
    Foreach(Form x in Application.OpenForms)

    formularios.Add(x)
    
    
    //recorremos la lista de formularios
    for(int i=0; i< formularios.Count;i++)
    {
    //validamos que el nombre de los formularios sean distintos al unico formulario que queremos abierto, en este caso que se cierren todos los formularios que no sean FormLogin

    if(formularios[i].Name != "FormLogin"
  
    formularios[i].Close();



    }

    
    FormLogin.Show();
```

Debemos copiar la lista de application.OpenForm si o si en otra lista, si lo tratamos de hacer directamente desde el Application.OpenForm no funcionara porque esta colección (application) cuando se esta iterando (con cualquier ciclo) no se puede modificar.